# Render a Rails Cell from erb file saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cells

I'm creating a CMS where I can define a dynamic template in the backend.

Using a drag and drop interface I'm saving to db, associated to a model, an erb template as string.

One example is this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <%= cell(:articles) %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <%= cell(:news) %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Rails Cell to render some list and some element.

How can I render (and evaluate), from my view, this ERB HTML saved as string in my DB?

Answer (score 0):

`ERB` is in standard Ruby library, so you need no gems to render `ERB` templates. You can render a template like so:

```
ERB.new(template_from_db).result(binding)
```

`binding` here is an instance of `Binding` class, that contains variables and methods defined at the current point. You don't need to manually instantiate this object as it's always there, in `Kernel.binding`. What you should pay attention here to is that this `cell` method should be available when you render templates from DB. `binding` is kind of local namespace, which you pass to `result` method, and ERB in its turn takes variables from this namespace when evaluates expressions in templates. Hopefully, my explanations are clear.

Everything should work in your case, because `cell` method is available in views and controllers. So the view would look like this:

```
<div id="articles">
  <%= ERB.new(@template_from_db).result(binding) %>
</div>
```

And in controller:

```
@template_from_db = Template.find(...).template
```